# ember.js how can I insert new record?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I am currently learning Ember.js and get stuck about the database. I want to create a site for comments, the users are able to write a comment on and see the comment after they submitted.

I have learned basic knowledge about how to display content from the official tutorial, but the data in the tutorial were hard-coded. If I need to insert one record, how can I achieve it? with a database or something easier?

thank you

Comment: Have you built an API or database before? I can share a few other resources that might be helpful, depending on the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is probably a little too general for StackOverflow since it is not really practical for anyone to provide a full tutorial here on this subject. Your best bet is to find an Ember tutorial for CRUD (Create Read Update Delete). The following post on Medium is probably your best option since it is a relatively recent one and particularly aimed at those who are new to Ember:

https://medium.com/ember-ish/the-simplest-possible-ember-data-crud-16eacee33ae6